# MysqlDB appends single quotes to string when trying to insert

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have been tirelessly trying to resolve the issue of using parameterized mysql query in python and haven`t found a solution yet.

What I am trying to do is this simple thing:-

```
  def parameterized_dml_query(self, sql, param):
    print sql, param
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    b='wtf'
    cursor.execute("""insert into table(schema_name) values %s""", (b,))
    self.connection.commit()
    logger.info("Row(s) were updated/ inserted :%s for sql : %s",str(cursor.rowcount), sql)
    no_of_rows_update = str(cursor.rowcount)
    return no_of_rows_update
```

But I always get this error :

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''wtf'' at line 1")
```

I don`t know why this ... API is adding single quotes to it.

Other questions :-
1. Is there any way to parameterize table_name.
2. In case of inserting NULL if I have a list of values like

```
list_of_keys = ''.join(['key1','key2','key3'])
list_of_values =''.join(['v1', None, 'v2'])

sql = """insert into table(%s) values %s"""
param = (list_of_keys, list_of_values)
```

And I call the `parameterized_dml_query` function it doesn`t work. So whats the best way to handle None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have sql syntax error. You forgot parentheses after values. Also `table` is a reserved word. I would quote with backticks. Use the following instead:

```
cursor.execute("""insert into `table`(schema_name) values (%s)""", (b,))
```

Also you can't pass fields as parameters. You can use:

```
list_of_keys = ''.join(['key1','key2','key3'])
sql = """insert into `table`(%s) values (%%s)""" % list_of_keys
cursor.execute(sql, ['v1', None, 'v2'])
```

Comment: In case when I pass multiple arguments it fails eg:  cursor.execute("""insert into table1(%s) values (%s)""", (query_columns,query_values,)) bcoz it appends ' single quotes  mysqlerror 1064 :'source_schema_name') values ('wtf')'